# glReadPixels depth_buffer_component always returns 1

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glut, glreadpixels

I'm trying to get world coordinates from any of my rendered vertices in OpenGL window (I prefer to use GLUT library). The problem is when I'm calling ***`glReadPixels`*** function to get depth value of a vertex, it always returns a 1 value, when I'm clicking my mouse anywhere.

I am stuck on this point, have already read a ton of articles, but didn't get any answer.

**Here is my code:**

*display function*

```
void display(){

 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
 glEnable(GL_DEPTH | GL_DEPTH_TEST);
 glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
 glDepthRange(200, 2000);

 //here i put some glBegins and glEnds

 glutSwapBuffers();}
```

*main function*

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){   

 glutInit(&argc, argv);
 glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
 glutInitWindowSize(1280, 720);
 glutInitWindowPosition(50, 86);
 glutCreateWindow("2D correlation function");
 glClearColor(1,1,1,1.0);

 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glLoadIdentity();
 glFrustum(-150, 150, -150, 150, 200, 2000);
 glutMouseFunc(mouse);
 glutMotionFunc(motion);
 glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
 gluLookAt(200,400,200,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
 glScalef(0.4, 0.4, 0.4);
 glutDisplayFunc(display);
 timer();
 glutMainLoop();


 return 0;}
```

*mouse clicking function*

```
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y){

 GLdouble objX, objY, objZ;
 GLdouble matModelView[16], matProjection[16];
 GLint viewport[4];
 glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matModelView);
 glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, matProjection);
 glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
 GLfloat winX = x;
 GLfloat winY = viewport[3] - y;
 GLfloat winZ = 0;
 glReadPixels(winX, winY, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ);
 cout << winX << " " << winY << " " << winZ << " " <<endl;
 gluUnProject(winX, winY, winZ, matModelView, matProjection, viewport, &objX, &objY, &objZ);
 cout << objX << " " << objY << " " << objZ << " " <<endl;}
```

Because of this, my world coordinates are displayed incorrectly:

example of mouse clicking

[image]

another example

[image]

I think i'm doing something wrong in *display* procedure

Comment: Why are you [putting a projection matrix (`glFrustum()`) onto the `GL_MODELVIEW` stack](https://web.archive.org/web/20171015143947/https://sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/projection_abuse.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter to [`glEnable`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnable.xhtml) has to be a single enumerator constant. The parameter is not a bit field.

The following is not valid and will generate a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error, which can be detected by [`glGetError`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetError.xhtml) or [Debug Output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output):

> ```
> glEnable(GL_DEPTH | GL_DEPTH_TEST);
> ```

It has to be

```cpp
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Anyway `GL_DEPTH` is not a valid parameter for `glEnable`, but it is possibly an parameter to [`glCopyPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glCopyPixels.xml).
Note, the value of the enumerator constant `GL_DEPTH_TEST` is *`0x0B71`*  and the value of `GL_DEPTH` is *`0x1801`*. A binary or (`|`) operation of the both constants won't make any sense.

Because of this the [depth test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test) has never been enabled and nothing was written to the depth buffer.

---

Further note, that the values which are accepted for the depth range [`glDepthRange`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDepthRange.xhtml) have to be in the range [0, 1]. The values which are passed to the `glDepthRange` are both clamped to this range before they are accepted.

This means, that

> ```
> glDepthRange(200, 2000);
> ```

is equal to

```cpp
glDepthRange(1, 1);
```

so the depth range is [1, 1] and all values returned by [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml) are 1, too.

Skip <s>`glDepthRange(200, 2000);`</s> to solve the issue.

---

`glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matModelView)` gets the current model view matrix from the `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix stack.
`glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, matProjection)` gets the current projection matrix from the `GL_PROJECTION` matrix stack.

So you should put the projection matrix on the `GL_PROJECTION` matrix stack and the view matrix on the `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix stack (see [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml)):

```cpp
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glFrustum(-150, 150, -150, 150, 200, 2000);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(200,400,200,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing GLUT_DEPTH to glutInitDisplayMode?

According to GLUT documentation that flag is needed to create a depth buffer.

Comment: thanks for advice, unfortunately nothing has changed